# In the movie Hush (2016), what twist is everybody talking about?

Tags: plot-explanation, ending, hush-2016

I think the movie narration is straightforward and didn’t see any twist in the climax. What twist are the people in reviews talking about?

Answer (score 3):

I believe they're referring to the fact that [Maddie is a deaf/mute character](https://robbinsrealm.wordpress.com/2016/10/04/hush-offers-a-clever-twist-to-a-home-invasion-horror-film/).

Normally, one would expect a lot of screaming and pleading for one's life from the victim in a film like this.  Perhaps some taunting calls from the killer.  Lots of sounds, basically.  However, since Maddie is deaf/mute, she can't scream or bargain verbally and has to find non-verbal ways of communicating with her assailant.  Likewise, the killer needs to find non-verbal ways to taunt his victim so she knows he's coming for her, in order to generate the kind of terror he clearly preys on.

So, it's not a twist in the sense of a "[twist ending](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TwistEnding)," but rather a twist in sense of "not your usual kind of slasher flick."

*(Standard disclaimer regarding people having lost hours of their lives to the TV Tropes website. It's like the Bermuda Triangle of the internet.)*

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen the movie, but based on the reviews (http://www.imdb.com/title/tt5022702/reviews) the movie is a home invasion horror film. The twist is *the protagonist is deaf*, so it's a new angle on the traditional genre.